# The meaning of a sentence: "He was complete even down to white kid gloves"

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does ***"He was complete even down to white kid gloves"*** infer in this context:

*Sally was usually good company at all times, pleasant to be out with; that was why they had made the trip together in the first place. Tonight she was in especially fine fettle.

“Are we getting looked at!” she reveled presently, not in the least disconcerted. “Very déclassée, I suppose, coming out alone together like this.”

“You know it isn’t that,” Marjorie teased her. “It’s probably that carrot thatch of yours, and the funny little phiz that goes with it. ” She undulated her wrist watch toward her. “You’re beautiful, my dear. ”

Sally squinted at one of the lanterns. “I must owe you money,” she said. “Trying to recall if I do or not. It’s the only way I can account for it. All right, you’re beautiful too, so there. I’m beautiful, you’re beautiful, what good does it do us? Two lonely old maids, twenty-four and twentyfive, all by themselves in the middle of the South American night. ”

“You shouldn’t have said that,” Marjorie said in a guarded voice, laughing silently down her chin. “Don’t look up, but we’re about to be accosted.”

**He was complete even down to white kid gloves.** He bowed low between them. “Would one of the senoritas care to do me the honor of dancing?”

The corner of Sally’s mouth was twitching in spite of her best efforts to control it. Close as he was, she managed to make herself audible to her friend without appearing to say anything. “Dare me?” she breathed. “Ow! what was that for?” she exclaimed, unabashed, a moment later as the point of her friend’s toe found her instep.

Marjorie saw that she would have to answer for the two of them. “No thank you,” she said with what gravity she could muster.

“Pardon,” the canvasser said stiffly. He gave another bow and left them.

“You hurt the poor man’s feelings,” Marjorie rebuked, holding her napkin to the side of her own mouth to keep the contagious laughter she was getting from the other girl from being seen.*

Comment: You still haven't told us the source of the quotation.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133419/discussion-on-question-by-eugene-the-meaning-of-a-sentence-he-was-complete-eve).

Comment: What part of that sentence are you having trouble with? "Complete"? "Even"? "Down to..."? "Kid gloves"?

Answer (score 3):

He is complete with respect to the expected clothing of a gentleman of the time and place.

It seems like there is a formal dance of some kind happening. Thus there would be formal clothing. In some times and places that might be a tuxedo. In other times it might be very different. This is supported by the formal speech given and the bow.

So it is saying that even this minor detail of white kid gloves has been satisfied. This allows the author to imply the rest of the clothing without having to go into details about it. You are told of the white gloves, told they are a final detail, and you then tend to fill in the rest of the formal costume.

Answer (score 0):

He was correctly dressed (presumably for a dance or ball) in every detail, including those [white kid gloves](https://www.etsy.com/uk/market/white_kidskin_gloves).

Answer (score 0):

**MORE CONTEXT!!** is always, always, always better when asking [meaning-in-context](/questions/tagged/meaning-in-context) questions...

"Kid leather" is a kind of soft leather made from kidskin, that is, the skin of young goats (sometimes it is made from the skin of other young animals, like lambs or calves). "Kid gloves" are gloves made of kid leather.

Because the leather is soft and delicate, "to handle something with kid gloves" is an idiom meaning to treat something with care. This delicateness goes both ways: You would not want to pick up a rare china vase while wearing rough workgloves because the gloves could damage the vase, but conversely you would not want to wear delicate kid gloves while working at a blacksmith forge because the expensive gloves would be damaged by the coal and iron. So someone wearing white kid gloves is assumed to be somewhat wealthy and, at least at that moment, not doing strenuous or dirty work; "a gentleman."

I have no idea what "complete" means exactly because you have not provided enough context, but I would guess it means that the man was dressed as a "gentleman" including all of the details. The fact that the text remarks on this makes me think his "completeness" is not entirely expected; perhaps the setting is a dance in the modern era, when people are not expected to go "all out" in such matters. But we need more context to say for sure.

Comment: I've added some more context but I'm afraid it won't be of much help.

Comment: No, it won't, because you haven't given the name of the work, nor the author, nor the era/location/season where this scene is set...

Comment: It's Cornell Woolrich's "The black alibi". The scene is set somewhere in Latin America. The story was completed in 1942, as far as I can recall.